# I can't set the property of the html Angular element

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm studying Angular on a training project, a project like and 2020, but nothing works. I have version 11, the tutorial uses 9. The tutorial defines a variable that changes the property of the html element, when creating it, I set the initial value:

```
menuMode = 'push';
```

and here I pass it to html

```
<ng-sidebar
    [mode]="menuMode"
>
```

The compiler throws an error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"over" | "push" | "slide"'
```

If you declare a variable like this:

```
menuMode: 'over' | 'push' | 'slide';
```

then the compiler skips, but this is somehow not correct, and if another property appears tomorrow

Comment: Can you show more code or a reproducible sample?  What is ng-sidebar?  Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences I notice in your sample code.  In a component class, this line will create a variable named `menuMode` with the value push.  No type is explicitly defined, but string will be inferred:

```
menuMode = 'push';
```

This line will create a variable named `menuMode` with the type of `'over' | 'push' | 'slide'`, but no value is assigned.  I believe the default state will be undefined:

```
menuMode: 'over' | 'push' | 'slide';
```

I suspect if you combine the two you'll get what you're after.

```
menuMode: 'over' | 'push' | 'slide' = 'push';
```

I'm not sure if you are the one who create `ng-sidebar`, because it is not a component I recognize.  Personally I try to avoid union types like this.  Since you have a controlled vocabulary I would define this as an enum:

```
export enum MENU_MODES {
  OVER: 'over',
  PUSH: 'push',
  SLIDE: 'slide'
}
```

You'd set your menu mode value, like this:

```
menuMode: MENU_MODES  = MENU_MODES.PUSH;
```

And the mode value inside of `ng-sidebar` would have to be of the same type.